# Laravel working but files missing in mapped directory from homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

I have just made the following Homestead.yaml file:

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/GIT/old-project
      to: /home/vagrant/old-project
    - map: ~/GIT/project
      to: /home/vagrant/project

sites:
    - map: old-project.app
      to: /home/vagrant/old-project/public
    - map: project.app
      to: /home/vagrant/project/public

databases:
    - name: old-project
    - name: project

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

`old-project` already existed. Next I ran `vagrant up`, then `vagrant ssh` then inside the vagrant box I ran `composer create-project laravel/laravel project 4.2 --prefer-dist`. Laravel installed. I edited my `/etc/hosts` file and now `project.app` leads me to the Laravel 'You have arrived' page. Great – everything works.

But on my mac, the folder ~/GIT/project is empty.

**What part of the installation process did I miss?** Is there anything I've done wrong that has prevented the files from mapping across correctly?

If I open ~/GIT/old-project all the Laravel files are there, and it works as I'd expect. I can't remember any difference in how I set up that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should run the `vagrant provision` command, to make the added directory (`~/GIT/project`) shared with the homestead.

When you run the command `vagrant up` for the first time, the directory `~/GIT/old-project` became shared with the homestead. However the directory `~/GIT/project` is not shared therefore it is empty on your mac.

> Note: When running the provision command, your existing databases will be destroyed and recreated.

Comment: I did six things [deleted the folder, recreated the folder, installed Laravel, ran vagrant provision, vagrant halt, vagrant up] repeatedly in a random order until it all worked OK! In future I will make sure the folder exists first of all.

Comment: My way to avoid this, is to map a main folder into `yaml` file and then every site maps to a subfolder of the main folder.